# Exclude item on OrderBy in a table - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a table sorted by properties "age" and "name" but I have a counter of rows (counterR) that shows the numbers of rows in the table. 
I want to exclude this item on OrderBy because is ordered too, I need it would be static and always ordered but I can´t.
There's the Plunker link of my problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/MJYayUANphxksbGkyEcj?p=preview

**HTML:**

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <table border="0">
    <thead>
      <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th ng-click="sortType = 'name';sortReverse=!sortReverse">NAME</th>
      <th ng-click="sortType = 'age';sortReverse=!sortReverse">AGE</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-init="counterR=incrementCounter()" ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse">
      <td>{{counterR}}</td>
      <td>{{item.id}}</td>
      <td>{{item.name}}</td>
      <td>{{item.age}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

**JS:**

```
 $scope.items = [
    {"name":"Jhon","id":"BB1","age":23},
    {"name":"Austin","id":"BB2","age":44},
    {"name":"Mark","id":"BB3","age":56},
    {"name":"Jenn","id":"BB4","age":15}
    ];
    var counterRow = 0;
    $scope.incrementCounter = function(){    
      counterRow = counterRow + 1;     
      return counterRow;   
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of storing the row number with the data - which doesn't work because the row numbers are not specific to a data row, but rather to a display position - you need to calculate the value "on the fly".  In the scope of an `ng-repeat` you can do this with the special `$index` variable.  That is, instead of

```
<td>{{counterR}}</td>
```

which reads a value from the data row, you would use

```
<td>{{$index+1}}</td>
```

(assuming sequential numbers starting from 1)

Comment: Thanks it works! But when I add a filter that the age of people is higher than 21 years old, the counter of rows is not sequential when apply the OrderBy on the items, Is there another way instead of $index? There's the Plunker link: http://plnkr.co/edit/unwHb9XS46S2qoc2QpJV?p=preview

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow strangers' plnkr links. If you want to post additional code here I'll be happy to look it over.  Alternately, you might want to check out AngularJS's ngRepeat documentation (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat); note from the examples that the symptom you describe is not expected.

Comment: Sure, I only change this:
HTML:
<tbody>
      <tr ng-if="item.age>21" ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse">
      <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
      <td>{{item.id}}</td>
      <td>{{item.name}}</td>
      <td>{{item.age}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>

Comment: When you use `ng-if` inside the `ng-repeat`, `$index` doesn't "know" that you're suppressing display of some elements.  Instead you can use `filter` on the `ng-repeat` element to express which rows should be iterated in the first place, and `$index` will then be incremented only for the rows that pass the `filter`